# Prolog change order of facts produces different outcomes

Tags: prolog

New to Prolog.  I have a tiny glitch that I cannot explain, but the program appears to work if I add other dictionary(X) facts.  This program takes a string list where the letters have been encoded and produces a decoded list.  Each letter represents a different letter in the list of words.  So go([abccd,edfgh,ade,ifb,kdl],X) returns X = ['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'HOW', 'ARE', 'YOU'].  The problem is if the dictionary('HOW') fact comes before the dictionary('YOU') fact, then the program returns X = ['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'HOW', 'ARE', 'HOW'].  Here is the glitchy code:

```
/*word bank*/
dictionary('HELLO').
dictionary('WORLD').
dictionary('HOW').
dictionary('ARE').
dictionary('YOU').

/*This spits out a single list where
the lengths of words in the dictionary
are matched to each word in the encoded 
message, so [abccd,edfgh,ade,ifb,kdl]
matches [HELLO,WORLD,HOW,ARE,HOW] or
any combination*/ 
sameLength([X|XTail],[Y|YTail]) :-
   dictionary(Y),
   name(X,L1),name(Y,L2),
   length(L1,Z),length(L2,Z),
   sameLength(XTail,YTail).
sameLength([],[]).

/*Turns a list of lists into
a single list*/
oneWord([X|XTail],Y) :-
   name(X,L),
   append(L,Z,Y),
   oneWord(XTail,Z).
oneWord([],[]).

/*This replaces the letters that are in
the dictionary, with the letters in the
message.  If at any point a letter has
been replaced because it is UPPERCASE,
and that letter is being replaced by
something else then fail, other wise,
the letter has to be lowercase*/
replaceLetters(List,[X|XTail],[Y|YTail],Result) :-
   (X<91,X=Y);(X>96),
   replaceP(X,Y,List,Result1),
   replaceLetters(Result1,XTail,YTail,Result).
replaceLetters(Result,[],[],Result).

/*the call to action*/
go(X,Y) :-
   sameLength(X,Y),
   oneWord(X,A),
   oneWord(Y,B),
   replaceLetters(A,A,B,C),
   B=C,
   !.

/*replace thanks to @repeat*/
replaceP(_, _, [], []).
replaceP(O, R, [O|T], [R|T2]) :- replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
replaceP(O, R, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- dif(H,O), replaceP(O, R, T, T2).
```

I would like to add that Prolog is cool.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for using dif/2! But name/2 is deprecated and outdated since  more than 3 decades - you are only permitted to use it if you wear 2in plateau shoes from the 1970s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution allowed me to understand from were the problem come out

```
go(X,Y) :-
    go(X,Y,[]).

go([],[],_Dict).
go([W|Ws],[T|Ts],Dict) :-
    assoc_codes(W,T,Dict,DictUpd),
    go(Ws,Ts,DictUpd).

assoc_codes(W,T,Dict,DictUpd) :-
    atom_codes(W, Cs),
    dictionary(T),
    atom_codes(T, Tcs),
    upd_dict(Cs, Tcs, Dict, DictUpd).

upd_dict([], [], DictUpd, DictUpd). % done, all went well
upd_dict([C|Cs], [D|Ds], Dict, DictUpd) :-
        memberchk(C-T, Dict)    % if C already 'assigned', must match D
    ->  T = D,
        upd_dict(Cs, Ds, Dict, DictUpd)
    ;   \+ ( memberchk(X-D, Dict), X \= C ),
        upd_dict(Cs, Ds, [C-D|Dict], DictUpd).
```

note the else branch: when C has not still been assigned, the same must be true for D. If we comment it out (i.e.

```
...
;   % \+ ( memberchk(X-D, Dict), X \= C ),
...
```

) we have the problem you report

```
?- go([abccd,edfgh,ade,ifb,kdl],X).
X = ['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'HOW', 'ARE', 'HOW'] ;
X = ['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'HOW', 'ARE', 'YOU'] ;
false.
```

It come out from the fact that 'L' must be assigned to *both* 'c' and 'g'.
After uncommenting the test, we have

```
?- go([abccd,edfgh,ade,ifb,kdl],X).
false.

?- go([abccd,edfch,ade,ifb,kdl],X).
X = ['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'HOW', 'ARE', 'YOU'] ;
false.
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to work this out.  I do not understand the syntax memberchk(C-T, Dict).  It is the C-T part that I don't recognize.

Comment: it's just a pair of character codes, stored in the simplest associative data structure I can think of: a list of pairs

Comment: ok.  I traced this and I see what you are doing.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

a couple of points:

1. I think you have the ';' precedence wrong and need another set of brackets.
2. The double HOW is actually a valid answer as you are not checking that e.g. both 'a' and 'k' map to H (by chance, the middle 'O' fits both 3-letter patterns).
3. There is probably a more 'Prolog' way to solve your problem, by using the natural unification of vars, i.e.

Respresent [abccd,edfgh,ade,ifb,kdl] as a similar list of vars:

```
[[A,B,C,C,D],[E,D,F,G,H],[A,D,E],[I,F,B][K,D,L]]
```

and store your dictionary as letter lists
e.g.

```
dictionary(['H','E','L','L','O']).
dictionary('['W','O','R','L','D']).
```

Then just use Prolog backtracking to match all the words:

```
solve([],[]).
solve([Word|Ps],[Word|Words]) :- dictionary(Word), solve(Ps,Words).
```

and call with something like

```
:- solve([[A,B,C,C,D],[E,D,F,G,H],[A,D,E],[I,F,B],[K,D,L]], Answer).
```

Note that this still has the same 'bug' your code has - there is no check all the vars match different letters - you will have to code for that...

Comment: Hi Thanks!  Transform sounds like a great solution and was the way I originally imagined the solution in my head, but did not know how to go about it.  The problem is exactly how to represent a potentially infinite list to variables so I will try this.  Awesome.